# から and まで be used for age?

Tags: grammar

Can I use から and まで to express an age range? For example I want to say "From 10 years old to 15 years old... :

> 十才から十五さいまでです。

Would this make sense? If not is there other simpler or better ways of expressing what I want to say?

Answer (score 1):

It's correct.
10才から15才迄です。
or 10才以上15才以下です。(write horizontally)

十才から十五才迄です。
or 十才以上十五才以下です。(write vertically)